# Android layout is completely messed up in older devices

Tags: android, xml

I have a simple layout like this. As it's a very big code, I am just pasting a part of it here (where the issue exists):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".candidate_registration"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/wave_1"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <!---some code here-->

        <!--issue lies in the below layout-->

        <RelativeLayout   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardview"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_reload">
                <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:id="@+id/reload"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/reload"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_send">
                <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:id="@+id/send"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/tick"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is how my layout looks like:

[image]

---

The issue is with the bottom `RelativeLayout`:

[image]

It shows like this:

[image]

This layout is completely squeezed to the point that it's barely visible. I tested it on `Pixel XL` phone having API 24. It's likely this issue occurs in other devices having the same API version.

How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT:** I tried changing the `RelativeLayout` to `ConstraintLayout` like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/cardview">
    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/reload"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/reload"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/tick"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the layout still shows like the image shown above.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is deprecated. You should probably rewrite your layout to use `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: I tried changing the `RelativeLayout` to `ConstraintLayout` but the issue is still there

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code for `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: I've edited my post, please have a look